Poisson brackets and graphical interpretation
Considering the case when $\frac{d}{dt}H=0$, for a function $F=F(\vec q,\vec p)$ one can write:
$\frac{d F}{dt}=\{F,H\}$ (I am assuming no explicit time dependency of F).
In the book: "Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" the following is said,


If $\{F,H\}=0$ then $F$ is a constant of the motion. We have therefore found a link between a conservation law ($F$ is a conserved quantity) with the Poisson bracket of the Hamiltonian and $F$ being zero.


I have 2 questions for this part:

a) Under which conditions is $\{F,H\}=0$?

b) Why $\{F,H\}=0$ implies that $F$ is a conserved quantity?


The 2nd thing I want to ask, has to do with a graphical interpretation of $\{F,H\}=0$,

The idea is that, in phase space (I believe we are in phase space but it is not explicitly said in the text), we consider $F(\vec q, \vec p)=const.$ and according to what is written, If $F(\vec q, \vec p)=const.$ then the vector $(\dot{\vec q},\dot{\vec p})=(\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec p},-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec q})$ is tangent to
the surface $F(\vec q, \vec p)=const. because
$$\nabla F (\dot{\vec q},\dot{\vec p})=0.$$
And, similarly for $H=H(\vec q, \vec p)$, $(\dot{\vec q},\dot{\vec p})$ is tangent to the surface $H(\vec q, \vec p)=const.$,
because
$$\nabla H (\dot{\vec q},\dot{\vec p})=0,$$
and so the trajectory of the system moves on the intersection of these two surfaces.
Now, I have some questions here about the construction of the sketch in the phase space, but also statements that imply certain ideas. I will list the questions below,  hoping someone can give me an intuitive explanation of them.

The arguments are $\vec q$ and $\vec p$, so each of them has components $q_i$ and $p_i$ for $i=1,2..N$. Is it correct to assume that eache component is actually a vector? For example our system can be that of N particles, so each particle has its own position and momenta.

Now, assuming that a point in the phase space represents a state of the $N$-particle system/ system of $N$ degrees of freedom. The trajectory traced by the point represents the time evolution of the state of the system. What I want to understand is why or how $(\dot{\vec q},\dot{\vec p})$ represents the trajectory? Wouldn't the vector $(\vec q,\vec p)=(\vec q(t), \vec p(t))$ itself, for values of $t$ represent the trajectory? Am I misunderstanding something here?

And the most important question here: With the information provided from the text (which I have fully provided here) it looks to me that the statement: "$F$ is a conserved quantity when $\{F,H\}=0$" is a direct interpretation of the description for the system in phase space. What I am trying to say is that, we come to the conclusion that F is conserved, not primarily because $\{F,H\}=0$, but because of what we find out from observing the phase space of the system.


But the thing that bugs me the most and should be highlighted is, the fact that the trajectory happens to be in the intersection of the two surfaces but no valid reason is given as to why it should be like this. What prevents us from considering a trajectory that traces any other possible path, that is not the intersection line between the two planes?
I am looking forward to insightful replies about all of this.

A good mechanics text covers all of these satisfactorily.

@CosmasZachos Can you recommend any? I don't want to go over all classical mechanics, as I understand it to an ok degree. I merely want the answers to these questions

Landau & Lifdhitz Mechanics should have standard answers to all your (essentials standard) questions. It's the big picture of mechanics as motions (trajectories) in phase space. If you know mechanics, what is the point of reading books for amateurs? In any case, Arnold's classic text is the go-to book on the subject.
a) $\{ F, H\}$ vanishes for constants of the motion: we then say H has a symmetry generated by F. Finding all such Fs of a given hamiltonian depends on its peculiarities, and is a broad problem! I'm not sure what further conditions you are asking about. Give me a Hamiltonian and I might be able to give you its Fs...
b) F is a conserved quantity because it does not vary with t, i.e. $\frac{dF}{dt}=0$ along the trajectory, the 2N-vectors $({\mathbf q}(t),{\mathbf p}(t))$ in phase space, for all ts.
Indeed,

Yes, as above, the trajectory is the collection of 2N-vectors whose time-derivatives $(\dot {\mathbf q}, \dot{\mathbf p}) $ tangent on a constant H surface, as well as a constant F surface. It is thus perpendicular to both $\nabla H$ and also $\nabla F$, neither of which vanishes.

The trajectory is  $(  {\mathbf q} (t),  {\mathbf p}(t) )$, and, at a given t, it is characterized by the above  time-derivative tangent $(\dot {\mathbf q}, \dot{\mathbf p}) $, which "chooses" the future location for an infinitesimally shifted t.

I don't understand your point. F must Poisson-commute with H, otherwise the hypersurface intersection would be pointles:  F would not intersect H, or it would in several lines/places, etc... Your diagram represents Poisson-commutativity in phase-space.



It might be best to try illustrating this picture with   N=2, and a trivial free $H= (p_1^2+p_2^2)/2$. In that case, you find that a rotation, $F=q_1p_2-q_2 p_1 $, Poisson-commutes with the Hamiltonian. Use overbars for all constants,  the point in phase space at t=0. The E-L trajectory $ (  {\mathbf q} (t),  {\mathbf p}(t) )= (\bar{q}_1+ t \bar{ p}_1, \bar {q}_2+ t \bar {p}_2,  \bar {p}_1,\bar p_2) $ is the intersection line of the $H=\epsilon$ and $F=f$ surfaces, $q_1(t)= (f + q_2(t) \bar p_1)/\bar p_2$.  Moreover, the phase space "velocity" $( \dot  {q}_1   , \dot  {q}_2 , \dot {p}_1, \dot p_2)= (\bar p _1, \bar p_2, 0,0) $ is perpendicular to both $\nabla H= (0,0,\bar p_1,\bar p_2  )$ and $\nabla F=(\bar p_2,-\bar p_1,-q_2,q_1)$, both nonvanishing. For a less trivial (indeed, deadly!) application of this geometry principle, see this.

